# How to log AJAX posted data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there a way to log AJAX posted URL and data? I tried many ways with mixed success. I appreciate your help. The code I tried is below:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'mylink',
  data: {
    id: 123, 
    name: John
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  error: function(req, err) { 
    console.log('my data' + url + data); 
  }
});
```

Comment: Note that Java and Javascript are two very different things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get those values back out of the $.ajax call, it doesn't create an object which contains that information. So you need to create that ability yourself. One way to make this easy would be to define your AJAX options outside the actual function call, and assign them to a variable which you can re-use and log values from:

```
var ajaxOptions = {
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'mylink',
    data: {id:123, name: "John"},
    dataType: 'json'
}
console.log('my data: ' + ajaxOptions.url + ' ' + JSON.stringify(ajaxOptions.data));
$.ajax(ajaxOptions);
```

That example logs the data every time, before the AJAX call starts. You could of course choose instead to do the logging only if there's an error, similar to your original version:

```
$.ajax(ajaxOptions).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log('my data: ' + ajaxOptions.url + ' ' + JSON.stringify(ajaxOptions.data));
});
```

You might want to also consider logging the error information at the same time...

Answer (score 1):

write the `console.log()` before the `ajax` call.

By the way, john, in the data needs apostrophes (`"john"`)

Answer (score 0):

while adding properties or values to data object you can console.log it inside the function but above ajax